# How to de-serialize POJO contains HashTable?

Tags: gson, resteasy, json-deserialization

I have pojo like this:

```
public class Test implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String hash;
    private java.util.Hashtable<Integer, Long> myTempTable;
    public java.util.Hashtable<Integer, Long> getMyTempTable() {
        return this.myTempTable;
    }
    public void setMyTempTable(java.util.Hashtable<Integer, Long> myTempTable) { this.myTempTable = myTempTable; }
    //And some few variables
}
```

In response I get this POJO in JSON format but while converting this JSON to "Test" java object like this.

```
gson.fromJson(tempString, Test.class);
```

It is giving error as

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Hashtable field <package_name>.Temp.myTempTable to java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

Why GSON is converting HashTable to LinkedHashMap?
And does this error means?

UPDATE: JSON File as

```
{
    "hash": "abc",
    "myTempTable": {
    "1": 30065833999,
    "2": 34364325903,
    "3": 536872959
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste the JSON here.

Answer (score 0):

For converting an Object to JSON String.

```
    public static <T> String convertObjectToStringJson(T someObject, Type type) {
        Gson mGson = new Gson();
        String strJson = mGson.toJson(someObject, type);
        return strJson;
    }
```

For converting a JSON String to an Object.

```
    public static <T> T getObjectFromJson(String json, Type type) {
        Gson mGson = new Gson();
        if (json != null) {
             if (json.isEmpty()) {
                    return null;
             }
        }
        return mGson.fromJson(json, type);
    }
```

where 
**Type** is type of your Object.

ex:

for object:

```
new TypeToken<YOUR_POJO>(){}.getType();
```

for list:

```
new TypeToken<List<YOUR_POJO>>(){}.getType();
```

Comment: Thanks @user2906641, but I think above thing will work when it receive HashTable and Test objects in different JSONs
Here I am getting Only one JOSN which is of User and that internally contains HashTable data.